# How to move portal artifacts from one environment to another in Redhat's 3scale

Tags: redhat, 3scale

We are working with Redhat's 3scale as our API management platform.

Currently we have a development environment and we are trying to build up another environment(***Staging/Production***).

Does anyone know how to move the artifacts(*Pages, Files, Partials, Layouts, Sections* etc.) of the Developer portal from one environment to another?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no API available yet for the Developers Portal, but it is on the product roadmap: [https://issues.redhat.com/browse/THREESCALE-361?jql=project%20%3D%20THREESCALE%20AND%20description%20~%20%22api%20cms%22](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/THREESCALE-361?jql=project%20%3D%20THREESCALE%20AND%20description%20%7E%20%22api%20cms%22)